# Sulu: Is it possible to limit Categories per webspace?

Tags: sulu

We have a sulu 1.6 multi site installation and are wondering if it is possible to limit the available categories per webspace?

Something like:

**webspace 1:**

- cat 1 and children only

**webspace 2:**

- cat 2 and children
- cat 3 and children

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is not possible. The closest thing I can tell you about is our `rootKey` parameter of the category API. This query parameter would allow you to only return children of the category with the given key. The key is the second line in the contact form.

So if you send a request like this, you should get only a subtree of the categories:

`/admin/api/categories?locale=en&flat=true&rootKey=category1`

However, the bad news is that this query parameter is not used by the `category_list` field type. However, a PR would be highly appreciated, and probably get merged :-)